# get API data that requires credentials from Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I was trying to get data from here -

https://myanimelist.net/api/anime/search.xml?q=full+metal

as shown in this API module -

https://myanimelist.net/modules.php?go=api

which allows only authenticated users to search anime/manga titles.

I can see data from browser. Is there any way I can get the data using Laravel or PHP?

Comment: you might want to look at GuzzleHttp, or you can use the php curl library. You need to send the username and password in the request, the api you refer to uses http auth which means you send the user and pwd in the header with each request

Comment: ok. I am looking at curl library now. thanks.